# How can i make the Invisible Walls script to work and take effect?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The idea is to make that when the player is walking to the edge of the terrain he will stop wont be able to continue and fall.

And in my case i want the objects that move forward when they collide with the invisible wall the object will turn lerp back and move to the other side of the invisible walls.

Another problem that might come up later i read about is that if the objects moving too fast to the invisible walls there is a bug that let them move through ? Not sure about it.

This is a screenshot showing the invisible walls. I created a box collider set the Is Trigger to be on and set the 500 600 500 same as the terrain size.

[image: Screenshot]

This is the script of the Invisible Walls: The script i attached it to the Terrain:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class InvisibleWalls : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {

    }
}
```

This is the script that create the space ships clone of them and make them move forward. But when they get to the edge of the terrain they just gone out. And i want them to lkerp/turn back to the other side.

This script is attached to the Spheres GameObject:

[image: Screenshot2]

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class SphereBuilder : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject SpaceShip;
    GameObject[] spheres;
    public float moveSpeed = 50;
    // for tracking properties change
    private Vector3 _extents;
    private int _sphereCount;
    private float _sphereSize;

    /// <summary>
    ///     How far to place spheres randomly.
    /// </summary>
    public Vector3 Extents;

    /// <summary>
    ///     How many spheres wanted.
    /// </summary>
    public int SphereCount;
    public float SphereSize;

    private void Start()
    {
        spheres = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("MySphere");
    }

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        // prevent wrong values to be entered
        Extents = new Vector3(Mathf.Max(0.0f, Extents.x), Mathf.Max(0.0f, Extents.y), Mathf.Max(0.0f, Extents.z));
        SphereCount = Mathf.Max(0, SphereCount);
        SphereSize = Mathf.Max(0.0f, SphereSize);
    }

    private void Reset()
    {
        Extents = new Vector3(250.0f, 20.0f, 250.0f);
        SphereCount = 100;
        SphereSize = 20.0f;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        UpdateSpheres();
        MoveShips ();
    }

    private void MoveShips()
    {
        foreach (Transform child in spheres[0].transform)
        {
            child.transform.position += Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
        }
    }

    private void UpdateSpheres()
    {
        if (Extents == _extents && SphereCount == _sphereCount && Mathf.Approximately(SphereSize, _sphereSize))
            return;

        // cleanup
        var spheres = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Sphere");
        foreach (var t in spheres)
        {
            if (Application.isEditor)
            {
                DestroyImmediate(t);
            }
            else
            {
                Destroy(t);
            }
        }

        var withTag = GameObject.FindWithTag("Terrain");
        if (withTag == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Terrain not found");

        for (var i = 0; i < SphereCount; i++)
        {
            var o = Instantiate(SpaceShip);
            o.tag = "Sphere";
            o.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform);
            o.transform.localScale = new Vector3(SphereSize, SphereSize, SphereSize);

            // get random position
            var x = Random.Range(-Extents.x, Extents.x);
            var y = Extents.y; // sphere altitude relative to terrain below
            var z = Random.Range(-Extents.z, Extents.z);

            // now send a ray down terrain to adjust Y according terrain below
            var height = 10000.0f; // should be higher than highest terrain altitude
            var origin = new Vector3(x, height, z);
            var ray = new Ray(origin, Vector3.down);
            RaycastHit hit;
            var maxDistance = 20000.0f;
            var nameToLayer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Terrain");
            var layerMask = 1 << nameToLayer;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, maxDistance, layerMask))
            {
                var distance = hit.distance;
                y = height - distance + y; // adjust
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Terrain not hit, using default height !");
            }

            // place !
            o.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
        }

        _extents = Extents;
        _sphereCount = SphereCount;
        _sphereSize = SphereSize;
    }
}
```

And this is a small short video clip showing what happen to the space ships when they get to the terrain edge:

[Spaceships video clip](https://youtu.be/D5YhLGb0uZc)

Update what i did so far:

In top of script added:

```
public Terrain terrain;
private Vector3 boundLower;
private Vector3 boundUpper;
```

In Start function i added:

```
private void Start()
    {
        spheres = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("MySphere");

        var withTag = GameObject.FindWithTag("Terrain");
        if (withTag == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Terrain not found");

        boundLower = terrain.transform.position - terrain.transform.size / 2;
        boundUpper = terrain.transform.position + terrain.transform.size / 2;
    }
```

But getting errors on both lines: size property not exist:

```
boundLower = terrain.transform.position - terrain.transform.size / 2;
boundUpper = terrain.transform.position + terrain.transform.size / 2;
```

And changed the MoveShips function to this:

```
private Vector3 direction = Vector3.forward;
    private void MoveShips() {
        foreach (var child in spheres) {
            var pos = child.transform.position + direction * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
            pos.x = Mathf.Clamp(pos.x, boundLower.x, boundUpper.x);
            pos.z = Mathf.Clamp(pos.z, boundLower.z, boundUpper.z);
            if (pos.x == boundLower.x || pos.x == boundUpper.x) direction.x = - direction.x;
            if (pos.z == boundLower.z || pos.z == boundUpper.z) direction.z = - direction.z;
            child.transform.position = pos;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to stop the spaceships when they collide with the invisible wall? Or dissapear like in the video?

Comment: @cjf93 i want them to stop when they collide with the invisible wall then turn around back and move to the other side of the invisible wall in the other side of the terrain and then when they collide with it to turn back again and so on nonstop. Like patrolling style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest modifying `MoveShips()` changing `Vector3.forward` to a variable and flipping it when bounds are reached:

```
private Vector3 direction = Vector3.forward;
private void MoveShips() {
    foreach (var child in spheres) {
        var pos = child.transform.position + direction * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
        pos.x = Mathf.Clamp(pos.x, boundLower.x, boundUpper.x);
        pos.z = Mathf.Clamp(pos.z, boundLower.z, boundUpper.z);
        if (pos.x == boundLower.x || pos.x == boundUpper.x) direction.x = - direction.x;
        if (pos.z == boundLower.z || pos.z == boundUpper.z) direction.z = - direction.z;
        child.transform.position = pos;
    }
}
```

This will remove unnecessary dependence on object collision engine for such a simple thing. Note, how this is making *all* ships to change direction when furthest reaches the bound. If you want them to move separately, you will need to move this logic to a separate script and attach it to a ship prefab.

And the bounds (`boundLower` and `boundUpper`) can be set either as script variables in editor or calculated from terrain, like:

```
boundLower = terrain.transform.position - terrain.TerrainData.size / 2;
boundUpper = terrain.transform.position + terrain.TerrainData.size / 2;
```

I would also suggest to move this:

```
var withTag = GameObject.FindWithTag("Terrain");
if (withTag == null)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Terrain not found");
```

out of `Update()` into `Start()` unless you do something really funky with it in the process.

Comment: I upodated my question with what i did with your solution where and how i added the variables and what i did in the Start function and in the MoveShips function. If you can check see if i added the variables right and if i did it right in the Start function i'm getting errors in the Start function. Thank you.

Comment: @TheLostLostit Yes. By `size` I meant `TerrainData.size`, of course. Updated the answer.

Comment: You should add after `withTag` check this: `terrain = withTag.GetComponent(Terrain);`

Comment: Ok it's almost working now. First when it collide the wall it's moving back but only to the start position. I wanted it to move back all the way to the other side of the terrain and collide with the other wall on the other side and then back to the other wall and so on. Another thing how to make the space ships to turn around with lerp or something that will make the ships turn in some kind of round ?

Comment: @TheLostLostit Check the `lowerBound` as it controls to what extent the ships will return back. You may also compleatly remove the `terrain` assigment if you will drop the terrain object into the script in editor. As for the smooth rotation, you may want to add an additional command to do that when they reach bounds, calling their `transform.Rotate()` like `transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed)`.

Comment: @TheLostLostit you may want also consider using `RequireComponent` annotation instead of throwing exceptions.

Comment: I added this line child.transform.Rotate (Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed); in each IF check inside the foreach loop. I also added as public the variable rotationSpeed to the top of the script. The result is that the ships rotate while they are moving. But what i wanted is when they collide the wall turn around and then move back. Not to make the turn and move or maybe with moving not sure. But as it is now it's not right.

Comment: @TheLostLostit This is not the topic of this question and this site is not a forum. You may mark this answered and create a new question or modify this one to include what you have along with your modified code. Also, it would be nice if you would try to think why it is that they are rotating while moving? Maybe you've lost `{ }`?

Answer (score -1):

Lets start working though your problems one by one :

Question : **The objects do not collide, why?**

> Answer : Objects do not collide from with-in the collider, only from the outside.

What you need in your case is 4 box collider, one at each edge of the map

Question : **Another problem that might come up later i read about is that if the objects moving too fast to the invisible walls there is a bug that let them move through ? Not sure about it.**

> This is only a problem with objects moving at bullet-like speeds, you could edit the rigidbody to have detection mode : "continuous" or continuous-dynamic which will avoid this issue

The scripts, i do not think you would need them in this case, your original idea was good, just the implementation with a single collider over the whole terrain, instead of 4 seperate "wall" colliders, was the issue. As for the rest of the logic, i did not try decipher through that, thus i can not comment on it.